# How to Insert android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" with intel xdk?

Tags: xml, android-activity, manifest

I need help about `androidManifest.xml` generated by intel XDK.

When I decode APK file with APKTOOL in can see in activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I need replace to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

I try to used for decode and encode apktool, but on my device I have a parse error.

Is it possible to influence the build in intel xdk, with `config.xml` or a plugin for this parameter?

Answer (score 2):

See http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html
You can add/modify the entry in your intelxdk.config.additions.xml

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I suppose the correct answer to the question would be:
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />

Answer (score 0):

For future reference also, while the answer was helpful, here's the link to the docs on [how to work with intelxdk.config.additions.xml](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/adding-special-build-options-to-your-xdk-cordova-app-with-the-intelxdk-config-additions-xml-file)